# JBossWS & Stateless WebServices, OutFaultInterceptor being ignored

Tags: cxf, jboss7.x, jbossws

We are tying to use a WebService OutFaultInterceptor as per [this blog post](http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2011/11/06/using-cxf-interceptors-to-do-some-magic-around-your-web-service-calls-1105/) and it doesn't seem to work in JBoss 7.x.

The problem is simple in that it just ignores the @OutFaultInterceptor annotation. I tested this by putting in a erroneous interceptor name and it didn't error out. Logging within the interceptor is simply not called (when the interceptor name is correct).

I have also tried using the [WEB-INF/jboss-webservices.xml to define out interceptors](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/Apache+CXF+integration#ApacheCXFintegration-Interceptors) but that also seems to get ignored.

Removing the @Stateless annotation also does not seem to help.

This was working fine on JBoss 5.1 but simply seems to not work on JBoss 7.x. What am I missing here?

Is there an alternative way to "translate" exceptions into soap faults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for using Apache CXF APIs and implementation classes you need to add a dependency to the org.apache.cxf (API) module and / or org.apache.cxf.impl (implementation) module.

```
Dependencies: org.apache.cxf services
```

**According documentation:**

> When using annotations on your endpoints / handlers such as the Apache
> CXF ones (@InInterceptor, @GZIP, ...) remember to add the proper
> module dependency in your manifest. Otherwise your annotations are not
> picked up and added to the annotation index by JBoss Application
> Server 7, resulting in them being completely and silently ignored

See also: [JBoss Modules](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/JBoss+Modules#JBossModules-UsingApacheCXF)

I hope this help.

Comment: I also needed the cxf.impl but that worked. THANK YOU!